# Создать папку с именем переменной, полученной от пользователя

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telegram, aiogram, pycharm

Телеграмм - бот на аиограме
Задача: при нажатии /старт бот спрашивает как зовут пользователя, юзер пишет "Иван", это записывается в переменную "answer_user", далее идет проверка существует ли папка с таким именем в корне, если нет, то создает её. Ниже код. Проблема в том, что папка не создается с такой переменной, с другими всё норм, что я не так делаю? Может есть другой способ записать сообщение юзера в переменную?

```
@dp.message_handler(commands=['start'])
async def start_handler(message: types.Message):  
    answer_user = await message.answer(f'Введите своё имя: ')

    if not os.path.isdir(str(answer_user)):
        os.mkdir(str(answer_user))
        os.chdir(str(answer_user))
```

Comment: кириллица не в той кодировке?

Comment: Почему вы решили что не создаётся? Может, создаётся не там, где вы её ожидаете? Проверьте `os.getcwd()` например

Comment: andreymal
 Потому что, если я создаю переменную user_full_name = message.from_user.full_name и её засовываю в os.mkdir(str(user_full_name)), то всё создается, то есть код правильный, проблема в переменной answer_user

Comment: пробовал и лат. и русские значения и числовые, ничего не работает, дело не в кодировке

Comment: @IvanZugzwang, а вы смотрели что у вас содержится в answer_user?

Comment: CausonQ
 оказывается нет)) был уверен, что там то что мне нужно, а там "message_id": 338, "from": {"id": 7028407852, "is_bot": true, "first_name": "СТД Тест", "username": "std_testbot"}, "chat": {"id": 810282300, "first_name": "Ivan", "username": "Navi_Vostenzuk", "type": "private"}, "date": 1709220719, "text": "Введите своё имя:" Что это за набор, я его не вызывал

Comment: @NaviVostenzuk это апдэйт. Вообще, так не удастся получить текст, введенный пользователем, в этом же хэндлере. Либо использовать fsm и после команды start ждать имя для папки от пользователя, либо отдельный хендлер для текста, но в этом случае папки будут создаваться при вводе любого текста

Comment: а может сделать отдельный txt/xlsx и туда записывать данные по юзерам, а уже оттуда выдергивать ФИО юзера? так сработает? как думаете?

Comment: @NaviVostenzuk для чего вообще, это спрашивать у юзера? Кто его знает, что он там понапишет. Я, когда-то, создавал папки для юзеров на сервере, просто присваивал в качестве имени - user_id. Это происходит без участия пользователи и названия папок вменяемые

Comment: Лучше всего сделать просто базу данных при помощи sqlite3 например. Никакой серьёзный программист не будет хранить данные приложения в excel или тем более в папках на диске

Comment: До серьезного программиста мне очень далеко, но всё идет к тому что действительно нужно делать БД, спасибо.

Comment: Попробуйте вместо `os.mkdir(str(answer_user))` это: `os.system(f'mkdir {answer_user}')`